# Prove if k odd, then $(a^m+b^m)|(a^n+b^n)$

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that for $k$ odd, it follows that $(a^m+b^m)|(a^n+b^n), \,\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, n = km, k, m \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}.$ I am trying to prove it by induction on $m.$ For $m = 1,$ I can prove that $(a+b)|a^k + b^k.$ Unfortunately, I am stuck at the induction step. Here I get the following: $a^{k(m+1)} + b^{k(k+1)} = a^{2lm}(a^{m+1}+b^{m+1})-b^{m+1}(a^{2lm}-b^{2lm}).$ I tried to use the induction hypothesis but could not achieve the final result. I need to show that the second term at the right hand side is divisible by $a^{m+1} + b^{m+1}.$ Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Hint : $$a^m\equiv -b^m\mod (a^m+b^m)$$ Can you finish the proof ?

Comment: Induction is not a good idea here.

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to do it by induction, since $m$ can be any natural number. I do not see how to use your suggestion.

Comment: If you raise my congruence to the $k$-th power, you immediately get the desired result. I have no idea how to apply induction over $m$ however.

Comment: Thanks. I got the result. But...without induction. Can you think of a way to show that the right hand term of the equation in my post is divisible by $a^{m+1}+b^{m+1},$ whereby the induction hypothesis is not yet used, $(a^m+b^m)|(a^n+b^n).$